# How to use assertRaises in table-driven tests where some tests raise and others do not

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest

How can I avoid calling the function I'm testing in two different places when writing table-driven tests where some of the tests should raise but others should not?

This is what I want to do but it fails passing `None` to `assertRaises`:

```
tests = [
   (0, None),
   (1, None),
   (-1, TooFewException),
   (99, None),
   (100, TooManyException),
]
for n, exc in tests:
    with self.assertRaises(exc):
        results = my_code(n)
        assert len(results) == n
```

The best I have come up with is this but the redundant call to `my_code` is bothering me:

```
tests = [
   (0, None),
   (1, None),
   (-1, TooFewException),
   (99, None),
   (100, TooManyException),
]
for n, exc in tests:
    if exc is not None:
        with self.assertRaises(exc):
            my_code(n)
    else:
        results = my_code(n)
        assert len(results) == n
```

---

After adding a helper func on our base test case using the answer from @AmuroRay this is now:

```
tests = [
   (0, None),
   (1, None),
   (-1, TooFewException),
   (99, None),
   (100, TooManyException),
]
for n, exc in tests:
    with self.assertRaisesUnlessNone(exc):
        results = my_code(n)
        assert len(results) == n
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`contextlib` has `nullcontext()` which can accomplish this. It's not really using fewer lines (without an ugly one-liner branch), but it eliminates the second user-code call:

```py
from contextlib import nullcontext

for n, exc in tests:
    if exc is None:
        cm = nullcontext()
    else:
        cm = self.assertRaises(exc)
    with cm:
        results = my_code(n)
        assert len(results) == n
```

Comment: Thank you, I used this to add an `assertRaisesUnlessNone` to our base test case and things are much nicer now!